# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/' failed

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm making a node JS server with WebSocket server on it.
Here is how I make the WS server:

```
const server = new WebSocket.Server({ server: app })
server.on('connection', (ws, request) => { 
   // some code
}
app.listen(8000, () => console.log('server is running'))
```

But on client side, there is an error:
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/' failed`

*It is important for me to make a WS server from node JS app, because this way I can see clients' cookies.*

Comment: Can you provide the we socket server module you are using?

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)